# Problems resizing GLUT window

Tags: c, opengl, window, glut

I have the following code and I can't resize the window. Any suggestions?

```
    GLsizei width = 600;
    GLsizei height = 600;
    GLfloat AspectRatio;
    int max = 500;

    double xmax = 2.0;
    double xmin = -2.0;
    double ymax = 2.0;
    double ymin = -2.0;

    using namespace std;

    void display()
    {
        gluOrtho2D(-2, width, -2, height);
        AspectRatio=1.0*width/height;
        mandelbrot();
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }

    void reshize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h) {
        GLsizei vsize;
        if(w<h) vsize=w; else vsize=h;

        glViewport(0,0,AspectRatio*vsize,vsize);
    }

    void mandelbrot()
    {
        ...
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutCreateWindow("mandelbrot Set");
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutReshapeFunc(reshize);
        glutMainLoop();

        return 0;
    }
```

**EDITED**

I changed to following and now it's OK.

```
void display()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-2, width, -2, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    mandelbrot();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h) {
    width=w; height=h;
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: what you mean you can't resize? with mouse? or windows after resizing doesn't update it's contents?

Comment: Hello, i mean when i drug the window with mouse it doesn't update the contents.It appears a black screen

Comment: try changing line in reshize to: 'glViewport(0,0,AspectRatio*vsize,AspectRatio*vsize);' also you need to set matrices: look at https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/256a-fall-2009/lectures/5a/code/starfield.cpp in reshapeFunc

Comment: My advice to you is to switch from GLUT to [`GLFW`](http://www.glfw.org/) which is much easier and straightforward to use. Portability is excellent too.

Comment: @fazo:Hello and thanks for the tip.Now,its ok !(i edited my post)

Comment: Fix the spelling when you're at it, it's "resize" and not "reshize".

Comment: @fazo:Hello,i wanted to ask maybe you have an idea how to do zoom according the code i have?